# How to Properly Stop Server-Side Interval in Socket.IO When Client Component Unmounts?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, frontend, backend

I have a React application where I'm using Socket.IO to fetch data from a server at regular intervals. The server sets up an interval for each connected client to send this data.

However, I've noticed that when a client component unmounts, the server's interval continues to fetch data for that client, leading to unnecessary network requests and potential memory leaks.

Below is my relevant code:

**Backend - socket.io.js:**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User connected: Socket ID - ${socket.id}`);

 socket.on('compareOeeData', async (requestData) => {
      const {  interval, machineName } = requestData;

      try {
        console.log(`Received 'compareOeeData' event from Socket ID - ${socket.id}`);

        setInterval(async () => {
          let endDate = moment();
          let startDate = moment().subtract(48, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]');
          endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]');
          const results = await controllerService.machineSpecificData(startDate, endDate, interval, machineName);
          socket.emit('compareOeeData', results);
        }, 5000);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error in partProduce: ', e);
        socket.emit('partProduceError', 'Failed to fetch part produce data');
      }
    });
  });
};
```

**Frontend - CompareOee.tsx:**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("compareOeeData", {
      interval: "1",
      machineName: selectedMachine,
    });

    socket.on("compareOeeData", (result) => {
      setData(result);
    });
  }, [selectedMachine]);
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to ensure that the server-side interval stops when the client component unmounts.